# Programmatically change icon of Safari browser extension?

Tags: safari, icons, safari-extension

I have a Safari browser extension with a disabled mode. What I'd like to do is to programmatically change the toolbar icon when the user enters disabled mode.

Is there an API which will allow me to achieve this and if so what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any toolbar items your extension has can be referenced as an array in

```
safari.extension.toolbarItems
```

Each toolbar item will have an image property which you can change. This will cause the toolbar icon to change immediately.

```
// Change the toolbar icon.
var changeToolbarIcon = function(newIconName) {
  var iconUri = safari.extension.baseURI + 'icons/' + newIconName;
  safari.extension.toolbarItems[0].image = iconUri;
};
```

[The Safari Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ExtensionToolbarItemClassRef/SafariExtensionToolbarItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009789)

Comment: Of note: The above applies to Safari Extensions JS. Safari App Extensions (new in Safari 10 / macOS 10.12) do not seem to currently provide a public API to change the toolbar item image (just enabled/disabled state and the badge).

Answer (score 1):

Using the new Safari App Extensions API, as long as you have a reference to an `SFSafariPage`, and that this page is not pinned (pinned tabs' windows are `nil`), you can get that page's tab's window's toolbar item, through a chain of callbacks, and then set the icon for each of these toolbar items.

```swift
extension SFSafariPage {

    func getContainingWindow(completionHandler: @escaping (SFSafariWindow?) -> Void) {
        self.getContainingTab { $0.getContainingWindow { completionHandler($0) } }
    }

    func getToolbarItem(completionHandler: @escaping (SFSafariToolbarItem?) -> Void) {
        self.getContainingWindow {
            ($0 == nil) ? completionHandler(nil) : $0.unsafelyUnwrapped.getToolbarItem { completionHandler($0) }
        }
    }
}


let tab: SFSafariTab = ...

tab.getToolbarItem { item in
    item?.setImage(NSImage(...))
}
```